# android 13 get fileList() returns null, java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-13

how to access my files from my own directory in android 13 ( I believe android 11 and above)?
I'm using this code, but files array always return null, and no errors in catch{}, just returning null.

**EDITED**
:and it's a hidden directory

```
String SRC_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/somePath/";
File directory = new File(SRC_PATH);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

I'm already using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

Comment: How is "/somePath/" your own directory?

Comment: If listFiles() returns null then there are probably no subfolders in it.

Comment: `and it's a hidden directory` ? You mean "/somePath/" ? That looks nit hidden. Whatever you consider to be a hidden ditectory.

Comment: And is "/somePath/" really a path or only a folder name?

Comment: @blackapps, i mean the path of my own directory, and for sure there is some pics and videos in it

Comment: Repeat: why is /somePath/ your own directory? It is time you also post the real path so we also can see that anything is hidden.

Comment: Further i did not talk about files in your own folder but about subdirectories.

Comment: You also better tell Android version of used device.

Comment: @blackapps, i have a directory in my phone, its path : "/raulApp/raulGallery/", raulGallery is a directory contains some pics and videos, when i try to get the files to a File[], the listFiles() always return null, in andoid 8 ( my old phone) everything was working as well (the code above), but now i have to change the code to work on android 13 ( my new phone )

Comment: That is an impossible path to begin with. And why do you call that hidden?. And of course you should have edited your post with it so it would be clear for new readers too what you do. For the rest you only repeated your problem. Did you already try with subfolders? If you get such a hint you are supposed to react.

Comment: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) of `listFiles()`: "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs." || a bit strange to have a `File`, returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory`, converted to `String` to concatenate some text to obtain a `File` again